# gdb can not open shared object file

Tags: linux, gdb, shared-libraries

I am trying to debug my application starting from console.

```
> gdb ./Geod
```

then in gdb

```
(gdb) run
```

and I get the output:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libGeo.Cored.so.1: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The system is configured as follows:

```
> echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    /home/paceholder/projects/geo/lib/debug

> ls $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    libGeo.Cored.so.1.0.0
    libGeo.Cored.so 
    libGeo.Cored.so.1
    libGeo.Cored.so.1.0


(gdb) show solib-search-path
    The search path for loading non-absolute shared library symbol files is
    /home/paceholder/projects/geo/lib/debug.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `set environment` command in gdb to change the environment gdb uses to launch the program you want to debug. Extract from the gdb help:

```
(gdb) help set environment 
Set environment variable value to give the program.
Arguments are VAR VALUE where VAR is variable name and VALUE is value.
VALUES of environment variables are uninterpreted strings.
This does not affect the program until the next "run" command.
```

Example with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
(gdb) set environment LD_LIBRARY_PATH /home/paceholder/projects/geo/lib/debug
```

Answer (score 4):

> `error while loading shared libraries: libGeo.Cored.so.1`

There are two likely causes:

- You forgot to `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` -- GDB creates a new shell, and un-exported variables  aren't copied to that new shell
- You have a `~/.bashrc` or some such that re-sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (don't do that!)

You can verify that either of the above is true by doing:

```
(gdb) shell
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$ ls $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: I added export statement to ~/.bashrc , now after opening the terminal I have correct output

    `>echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH  
        /home/paceholder/projects/geo/lib/debug`

but after I try as you described with `(gdb) shell` I got nothing, somehow `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` got overwritten after the start of gdb