# GDB "cannot open shared object file" Issue

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, linker-errors, dynamic-linking

I've already read [gdb says "cannot open shared object file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932384/gdb-says-cannot-open-shared-object-file) and [gdb can not open shared object file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254546/gdb-can-not-open-shared-object-file) and followed the instructions.

I have a binary which is linked to a shared library file (`/zzz/yyy/xxx.so`). After I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/zzz/yyy/` and run the binary without GDB, it executes very well.

However, when I was trying to use GDB to debug this binary, GDB says:

> `error while loading shared libraries: xxx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I already have (set in .gdbinit):

```
(gdb)show env LD_LIBRARY_PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = "/zzz/yyy/"
```

and

```
(gdb) show solib-search-path
The search path for loading non-absolute shared library symbol files is "/zzz/yyy/".
```

and in my system:

```
% printenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/zzz/yyy
```

What's the other possible reasons why GDB still can't find this shared library?

Comment: In these cases it is useful `strace`. Try running `strace -o out.txt gdb ./myprogram` and then, after the error happens quit the debugger and do `grep xxx.so out.txt` to see where gdb is looking for the library.

Comment: @rodrigo: Thanks. I realize it's because I have an extra LD_LIBRARY_PATH directory in ~/.cshrc. There is an x64 version library file (my application is built for x86) in that directory. The x64 version file makes the GDB complain. BTW, the strace doesn't seem to work well in this case, it didn't show that GDB has ever tried to access the x64 library (but GDB should have done that).

Comment: Maybe gdb forked. `strace` by default only traces one process. You can use `strace -f` to trace the child process also and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, when I was trying to use GDB to debug this binary, GDB says: error while loading shared libraries: xxx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

You are mistaken: it's not GDB that says that, it's the dynamic loader. GDB itself doesn't care what `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set to, it simply runs your program. But your program can not run.

The most common cause: you are re-setting your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your `~/.cshrc`, and  GDB runs your program in a separate shell, and that shell reads your `.cshrc`, so your program executes with incorrect environment.

The fix is to make `.cshrc` *not* set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for non-interactive shells. See e.g. [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26686) answer.