# load shared lib in GDB session

Tags: linux, gdb, shared-libraries

I have a binary that depends on a certain shared lib and when I try to run the binary under GDB, it says that this shared lib is not found: `error while loading shared libraries: libshr1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

How can I tell to GDB where this library is located and load it? I am looking for something similar to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but I want to set it directly from the GDB session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I tell to GDB where this library is located and load it? I am looking for something similar to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but I want to set it directly from the GDB session.

You can't -- the error is not coming from GDB; it's coming from the dynamic loader.

There are two ways to tell the dynamic loader where to find this library: using `-rpath` at link time, or setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

If for whatever reason you don't want to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before invoking GDB, you can do so at the `(gdb)` prompt using `set env` command:

```
(gdb) set env LD_LIBRARY_PATH /dir/where/libshr1/is/located
(gdb) run
```

P.S. If this doesn't work, your *shell* might be resetting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` inappropriately. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23464503/50617).

Comment: I mean, technically that's *exactly* like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but set from the GDB session.

Answer (score -1):

The gdb(1) *load* command will probably do what you need: bring the shared library into memory (along with its symbol table, if any).

```
$ gdb
(gdb) info load
(gdb) load mylib.so
(gdb) run
```

Comment: `(gdb) load libshr1.so 
`system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7fce000' has disappeared; keeping its symbols.
You can't do that when your target is `exec'`

Comment: The GDB `load` command does something else entirely.